# A question about Hagan's 2002 SABR paper "Managing Smile Risk"

Tags: sabr

I'm reading Hagan's 2002 paper Managing Smile Risk originally published on the WILMOTT magazine, and got something confusing.

**The set up**: Consider a European call option on an asset $A$ with exercise date $t_{ex}$ , and strike $K$. If the holder exercises the option on $t_{ex}$, then on the settlement date t_set he receives the underlying asset A and pays the strike $K$.

Let $BS(f,K,σ_B,t_ex)$ be Black’s formula for, say, a call option. According to the SABR model, the value of a call is as equation (3.5)
$$V_{call}=BS(f,K,σ_B (K,f),t_{ex})$$

Here $\sigma_B$ is the implied volatility. Also, at-the-money volatility is defined as the implied vol when $K$ is $f$:
$$\sigma_{ATM} := \sigma_B(f,f)$$

The SABR model is
$$d\hat{F}=α\hat{F}^β dW_1,\quad \hat F(0)=f $$
$$d\hat α = v \hat \alpha dW_2, \quad \hat \alpha(0) = \alpha$$
$$dW_1 dW_2=ρ dt$$

Then in pp95, it starts to discuss **the two approaches to calculate Delta risk** --

The delta risk expressed by the SABR model depends on whether one
uses the parameterization $α$, $β$, $ρ$, $ν$ or $\sigma_{ATM}$, $\beta$, $\rho$, $\nu$.

1. Suppose    first we use the parameterization $α$, $β$, $ρ$, $ν$, so
   that $σ_B (K,f)≡σ_B    (K,f ; α,β,ρ,ν )$. Differentiating respect to
   $f$ yields  the Δ risk in equation (3.9)
   $$Δ≡\frac{∂V_{call}}{∂f}=\frac{∂BS}{∂f}+\frac{∂BS}{∂σ_B}
   \frac{∂σ_B(K,f;α,β,ρ,ν ))}{∂f}$$
2. Now suppose we use the parameterization $σ_{AMT}$, $β$, $ρ$, $ν$.
   Then $α$ is a function of $σ_{ATM}$ and $f$ defined implicitly by $\sigma_{ATM} := \sigma_B(f,f)$.
   Differentiating (3.5) now yields the Δ risk as in Equation (3.10)
   $$ Δ≡\frac{∂BS}{∂f}+\frac{∂BS}{∂σ_B}
    \left[\frac{∂σ_B (K,f; α,β,ρ,ν)}{∂f}  + \frac{∂σ_B (K,f;    α,β,ρ,ν)}{∂α} \frac{∂α(σ_{ATM},f)}{∂f}\right] $$

Then in the 2nd approach, it says:

> The delta risk    is now the  risk to changes in $f$ with $σ_{ATM}$
> held fixed. The last term    is just  the change in $α$ needed to keep
> $σ_{ATM}$ constant while $f$    changes.  Clearly this last term must
> just cancel out the vertical    component  of the backbone, leaving
> only the sideways movement of the    implied volatility curve. Note
> that this term is zero for $β=1$.

I'm lost here, what is **the last term** ?

I tried to calculate "the change in $α$ needed to keep $σ_{ATM}$ constant while $f$    changes", the change of $\sigma_{ATM}$ is

$$\delta \sigma_{ATM} = \frac{\partial\sigma_{ATM}}{\partial f} \delta f + \frac{\partial \sigma_{ATM}}{\partial \alpha} \delta \alpha$$

So to keep $\sigma_{ATM}$ constant, i.e. make the change $\delta \sigma_{ATM} = 0$, the change in $\alpha$ is

$$\delta \alpha = - \frac{  \frac{\partial \sigma_{ATM} } {\partial f}       } { \frac {\partial \sigma_{ATM}}{\partial \alpha} } \delta f$$

But such amount is not in equation (3.10).

So what is the **the last term** indeed?

Comment: The last term is $\frac{∂σ_B (K,f;    α,β,ρ,ν)}{∂α} \frac{∂α(σ_{ATM},f)}{∂f}\,.$ Simplify your notation to see that your formulas involving $\delta$ have indeed a lot to do with this.

Comment: @KurtG. but $\frac{∂σ_B (K,f;    α,β,ρ,ν)}{∂α} \frac{∂α(σ_{ATM},f)}{∂f}$ is $\frac{∂σ_B (K,f;    α,β,ρ,ν)}{∂f}$, while my formula with $\delta$ contains $\frac{\partial \sigma_{ATM}}{\partial f} / \frac{\partial \sigma_{ATM}}{\partial \alpha}$ is $\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial f}$, to make this the same we need $\sigma_B = \alpha$, but this is not the case, no?

Comment: You are lost in that overcomplicated notation. Why on earth is there $\sigma_{ATM}$ and $\sigma_B\,?$ Your formula is equivalent to  $$\frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial f}=\frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial\alpha}\frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial f}$$ which looks like Hagan's last term to me.

Comment: @KurtG. thanks pointing out the way to think. I think i got it, the *last item* i suppose is $\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial f}$

Comment: Great that you got the maths. Thinking mathematically will also help with the Hagan exegesis: what needs to be zero to make his two $\Delta\,$s the same? Note that I am not interested whether we call that a *last term* or whatever.

Comment: @KurtG. Pls consider bringing your comments together as an answer.

Comment: @Alper I take this as an upvote but think that OP could learn far more by writing an own answer. In the end it is just the chain rule we know from calculus.